# How can I print e-mails landscape from Outlook 2010?

Tags: printing, ms-office

Maybe I'm missing something but from the Print dialog in Office 2010 (OS X 10.7.3) I can't find where to set orientation?

It doesn't appear under Outlook, Layout, Color Matching, Paper Handling, Paper Feed, Cover Page or Printer Features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Entourage 2007 so I'm assuming that it work on Outlook 2010.

Try File > Page Setup then select Landscape. Or File > Print... > then select "Layout" > and change it Landscape.

Comment: nope: only options under layout are pages per sheet, border, two-sided, reverse page orientation and flip horizontally

Comment: Have you tried flip horizontally?

Comment: yeah i tried that and it just prints a mirror image :) got it now though- see my answer above

Answer (score 1):

1. In Outlook, go to File > Print > Define Styles > Edit
2. Select 'Paper' tab
3. Under 'Orientation' select your preference, Portrait or Landscape
4. Print

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2011 for Mac, select page settings from the file menu.
Switch it to landscape, print, and switch it back to portrait mode.